# Laravel Integrity constraint violation on db migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-migration, laravel-5.3

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table `users`)
```

I know this has been answered several times, but still i cant figure our whats wrong with my migration.

**First i call the partner migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('company_name', 50);
        ...
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('partners');
}
```

**Then i call the Users migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('partner_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('email', 70)->unique();
        $table->string('first_name', 50);
        $table->string('last_name', 50);
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('image', 200)->nullable();
        $table->string('gender', 10)->nullable();
        $table->string('phone', 25)->nullable();
        $table->string('nationality', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('address', 200)->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
        $table->string('single_signon', 30)->nullable();

        // Checks if mysql or mariadb supports json data type
        if ((DB::connection()->getPdo()->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME) == 'mysql') && version_compare(DB::connection()->getPdo()->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION), '5.7.8', 'ge')) {
            $table->json('settings')->nullable();
        } else {
            $table->text('settings')->nullable();
        }

        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('partner_id')->references('id')->on('partners')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('users_partner_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

**Last i call the notification migration:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('notification_type', 10);

            // Checks if mysql or mariadb supports json data type
            if ((DB::connection()->getPdo()->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME) == 'mysql') && version_compare(DB::connection()->getPdo()->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION), '5.7.8', 'ge')) {
                $table->json('notification')->nullable();
            } else {
                $table->text('notification')->nullable();
            }
            $table->boolean('seen');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('notifications', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('notifications_user_id_foreign');
    });
    Schema::drop('notifications');
}
```

Can anybody figure out whats wrong with this? i am using laravel 5.3 and php7

Comment: Show the whole code for up() in users migration

Comment: i have updated the code, thanks

Comment: Do you try to call rollback?

Comment: No i usually just do migrate:refresh --seed

Comment: It looks like that you fk to users table. Do you have any other tables?

Comment: It seems there are not all the migrations. Why do you remove foreign key `'users_partner_id_foreign` and you don't have set foreign key for `partner_id` column? Maybe you create this foreign key in other migration?

Comment: Sorry guys i was so fedup of it that i just removed the foreign keys, didnt realize it. It does have a foreign key. I have updated the code now. And have also added the 3rd table that i have, which i didn't share for the sake of simplicity. Thanks :)

Comment: You do not need to specifically remove foreign key in your `down()` method. Try without that. It always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in migration order. It's better to include the migrations in one file and drop the child before the parent, like this:

```
public function down(){
  Schema::drop('notifications');
  Schema::drop('users');
  Schema::drop('partners');
}
```

That's because Laravel tries to drop `users` table before `notifications` table, which include `user_id` column that has reference in `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::drop('tableName');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
```

disable foreign key check while droping the table